# Docker command line arguments with values, when to use space vs when to use equals sign

Tags: bash, docker, command-line-interface

I'm using the Docker command line interface. I've found out (by trying it) that I can add arguments with values both like this:

```
$ docker build -t foo/bar .
```

And like this:

```
$ docker build -t=foo/bar .
```

Both have the same result.

However, I can't seem to find in the docs which version is preferred (or deprecated). I also haven't found explicit mentioning of both forms, just implicit examples of both forms.

For example:

In [the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#option-types) I see

> Boolean options take the form `-d=false`.

A little later I see:

> `$ docker run -i -t --name test busybox sh`

And below that I see:

> Options like `--name=""` expect a string, and they can only be specified
>   once. Options like `-c=0` expect an integer, and they can only be
>   specified once.

In [another part of the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name---name) I see:

> `$ docker run --name my-redis -d redis`

So both forms are used and (I suspect) valid.

**Is this true? Does it make a difference which form I use?**

Comment: Short answer is no; see the answer in that question if you're curious about more details.

Answer (score 1):

Using space instead of = is more UNIX way of passing values to the command line arguments.
However, for being more descriptive while writing the command = can be used.